# How do I go about creating a certain port number for web application?

Tags: php, networking, port, centos7

I am running my web application on a centos 7.8 and presently I only have a few line of HTML code. I want to access the file via a different port other than the default port 80. so that I can access the file like say [www.example.com:50502](http://www.example.com:50502). what configuration or PHP code can I use to achieve it. Please also note that there are many applications on the server, I want some to run on the normal port 80 and some to be accessible only on the defined port. Your answers will be much appreciated

Comment: Are you saying you *cannot* access the port `50502` while their server is running. You do realize that their server needs to be running right?

Comment: yes, server running what i need to know is how to access that my created file or application using a URL  and a port number unlike using just the URL to access the file on the server

Comment: read about apache/nginx - whichever you're using on your centos - and learn how to configure it. ask related questions on serverfault.

Comment: if you using Apache as webserver, i think you can make apache listen to a specific port.
https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/bind.html

Comment: And also apart from above you need to allow access to that specific port on your firewall to access from outside